# How to read column wise data from the attached SemEval 2017 text File

Tags: python-3.x

I want to read the Label column and text column from the data file. Earlier I have used pandas to read column-wise data. However, the format of the SemEval2017 file is not allowing me to read data column-wise. How to separate label and text from the file. Earlier, I used the following code to read the 'tweets' column from a file.

```
df = pd.read_csv('c:/STS-Gold1.csv', sep=';')
for i,ir in df.iterrows():
    txt = preprocess_text(str(ir['tweet']))
    myData.append(txt)
```

A snapshot from the text file has been attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6A9q.png). I tried to save the file as .csv format but no use.

Few Examples from the file are as follows:

```
620013074272137216  positive    Call for reservations for lunch or dinner tomorrow (yep Sunday!). Happy to accommodate guests in town for the MISS USA Pageant 346-5100 
620015047889154048  neutral "Miss Universe Org prez tells me #Trump won't attend Sunday's Miss USA event He's missed some in the past, but he said recently he'd be here"   
620015649151021056  neutral Trump said June 30th that he'd be at Miss USA pageant in Baton Rouge. Organizers say he's not coming. No word yet from his camp on his plans    
620017122081685504  neutral Haven't read To Kill a Mockingbird in years. That may be a good thing for when I read Go Set a Watchman. Might make it less heartbreaking.
```

Comment: Can you please put few records of your data and make your example reporoducible, It will help everyone to understand and probably you will get better help

Comment: I have edited my question.